# Hold background-Image while resizing Browser Window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a Roulette game using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

**I have a problem while resizing the Browser Window.**

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/5wrfzbaj/3/

The background-image is moving with it and because of that line showing. When the roulette stopped, it showing different color depends on how big your browser size is.

I want the background image to be "fixed" with the wining line but I don't really know how to do that.

HTML:

```
<main>
   <h1>Rulette</h1>
    <div class="rolling-area">
        <div class="rolling-indicator"></div>
        <div class="rolling-box"></div>
    </div>
</main>
<script src="roll.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1{
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.rolling-area{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0,.5);
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.rolling-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/P0oti92.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: auto 100px;
    background-position: 520px;
    transition: 8s;
}

.rolling-indicator{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0,.5);
    width: 3px;
    left: 50%;
    top: -15px;
    height: calc(100% + 30px);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
let startingPosition = "520px";
let randomPosition;
let minimumPosition = 2000;

//Roll the rulette
function roll() {
    console.log("Rolling!");
    randomPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15000 + minimumPosition);
    console.log(randomPosition);
    document.querySelector(".rolling-box").setAttribute("style", "background-position: " + randomPosition + "px center;");
}

// Restart the rulette to standart position
function positionZero() {
    document.querySelector(".rolling-box").setAttribute("style", "background-position: 2000px center;" + " transition: 0s;");
    console.log("Zero");
    setTimeout(positionStandrad, 1);
}

function positionStandrad() {
    document.querySelector(".rolling-box").setAttribute("style", "background-position: " + startingPosition + " center; transition: 1s ease-out;");
    console.log("Standar");
}

//setInterval(roll, 1000);
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle/codepen to test your code? Just a suggestion, try using % dimentions instead of pixels

Comment: Or use `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, and `vmax`, which are percentages of the display size

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by changing the `background-position` property to use percentage values (50%) instead of pixels (520px). For offsets, you can use the `calc` function: `background-position: calc(50% + 2000px);`.

result: https://jsfiddle.net/sLfyerd7/1/

Other changes:

- Changed `startingPosition` to be a number instead of a string
- Stored a reference to '.rolling-box' instead of looking it up in every function
- Used `elem.style.backgroundPosition` instead of `elem.setAttribute('style', 'background-position: ...')`